# Panda dataframe making every unique ID number NAT

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, and for every unqiue ID, make the first 'Diff' column NaT, for example my data starts off looking like

```
index   DEVICE_ID      DIFF
0        12             Nat
1        12              20
2        12              30
3        13              40
4        13              40
5        13              21
6        14               9
7        14              10
```

But I want the resulting dataframe to look like the one below

```
index   DEVICE_ID      DIFF
0        12             Nat
1        12              20
2        12              30
3        13             Nat
4        13              40
5        13              21
6        14             Nat
7        14              10
```

Sorry for the poorly worded question

Comment: `NaT` are mostly used for missing DateTime values, although there is intercompatibility between `NaT` and `NaN`. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`df.duplicated()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
df.loc[~df.DEVICE_ID.duplicated(),'DIFF'] = pd.NaT
>>df

   index  DEVICE_ID DIFF
0      0         12  NaT
1      1         12   20
2      2         12   30
3      3         13  NaT
4      4         13   40
5      5         13   21
6      6         14  NaT
7      7         14   10
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I just want to ask ~df.DEVICE_ID.duplicated() means?

Comment: @samari708 `df.duplicated()` gives you True for all duplicated values barring the first one, while `~` is a sign which inverts the condition, basically pulling the first of the duplicate values. :)